# Is there a way to speed up Numpy array calculations when they only contain values in upper/lower triangle?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'm doing some matrix calculations (2d) that only involve values in the upper triangle of the matrices.

So far I've found that using Numpy's [`triu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) method ("return a copy of a matrix with the elements below the k-th diagonal zeroed") works and is quite fast.  But presumably, the calculations are still being carried out for the whole matrix, including unnecessary calculations on the zeros.  Or are they?...

Here is an example of what I tried first:

```
# Initialize vars
N = 160
u = np.empty(N) 
u[0] = 1000
u[1:] = np.cumprod(np.full(N-1, 1/2**(1/16)))*1000
m = np.random.random(N)

def method1():
    # Prepare matrices with values only in upper triangle
    ones_ut = np.triu(np.ones((N, N)))
    u_ut = np.triu(np.broadcast_to(u, (N, N)))
    m_ut = np.triu(np.broadcast_to(m, (N, N)))

    # Do calculation
    return (ones_ut - np.divide(u_ut, u.reshape(N, 1)))**3*m_ut
```

Then I realized I only need to zero-out the final result matrix:

```
def method2():
    return np.triu((np.ones((N, N)) - np.divide(u, u.reshape(N, 1)))**3*m)
assert np.array_equal(method1(), method2())
```

But to my surprise, this was slower.

```
In [62]: %timeit method1()                                                                                
662 µs ± 3.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [63]: %timeit method2()                                                                                
836 µs ± 3.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Does numpy do some kind of special optimization when it knows the matrices contain half zeros?

I'm curious about why it is slower but actually my main question is, is there a way to speed up vectorized calculations by taking account of the fact that you are not interested in half the values in the matrix?

***UPDATE***

I tried just doing the calculations over 3 of the quadrants of the matrices but it didn't achieve any speed increase over method 1:

```
def method4(): 
    split = N//2 
    x = np.zeros((N, N)) 
    u_mat = 1 - u/u.reshape(N, 1) 
    x[:split, :] = u_mat[:split,:]**3*m 
    x[split:, split:] = u_mat[split:, split:]**3*m[split:] 
    return np.triu(x) 
assert np.array_equal(method1(), method4())
```

```
In [86]: %timeit method4()                                                                                
683 µs ± 1.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

But this is faster than method 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution that is faster in some cases but slower in some other cases.

```
idx = np.triu_indices(N)

def my_method():
    result = np.zeros((N, N))
    t = 1 - u[idx[1]] / u[idx[0]]
    result[idx] = t * t * t * m[idx[1]]
    return result
```

Here, the computation is done only for the elements in the (flattened) upper triangle. However, there is overhead in the 2D-index-based assignment operation `result[idx] = ...`. So the method is faster when the overhead is less than the saved computations -- which happens when `N` is small or the computation is relatively complex (e.g., using `t ** 3` instead of `t * t * t`).

Another variation of the method is to use 1D-index for the assignment operation, which can lead to a small speedup.

```
idx = np.triu_indices(N)
raveled_idx = np.ravel_multi_index(idx, (N, N))
def my_method2():
    result = np.zeros((N, N))
    t = 1 - u[idx[1]] / u[idx[0]]
    result.ravel()[raveled_idx] = t * t * t * m[idx[1]]
    return result
```

Following is the result of performance tests. Note that `idx` and `raveled_idx` and are fixed for each `N` and do not change with `u` and `m` (as long as their shapes remain unchanged). Hence their values can be precomputed and the times are excluded from the test.
(If you need to call these methods with matrices of many different sizes, there will be added overhead in the computations of `idx` and `raveled_idx`.) For the comparision, `method4b`, `method5` and `method6` cannot benefit much from any precomputation. For `method_ne`, the precomputation `M = np.tri(N, dtype=bool)` is also excluded from the test.

```
%timeit method4b()
%timeit method5()
%timeit method6()
%timeit method_ne()
%timeit my_method()
%timeit my_method2()
```

Result (for N = 160):

```
1.54 ms ± 7.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.63 ms ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
167 µs ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
255 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
233 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
177 µs ± 907 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

For N = 32:

```
89.9 µs ± 880 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
84 µs ± 728 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
25.2 µs ± 223 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
28.6 µs ± 4.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
17.6 µs ± 1.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
14.3 µs ± 52.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For N = 1000:

```
70.7 ms ± 871 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
65.1 ms ± 1.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
21.4 ms ± 642 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
3.03 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
15.2 ms ± 95.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
12.7 ms ± 217 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using `t ** 3` instead of `t * t * t` in `my_method` and `my_method2` (N = 160):

```
1.53 ms ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.6 ms ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
156 µs ± 1.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
235 µs ± 8.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.4 ms ± 4.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.32 ms ± 9.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Here, `my_method` and `my_method2` outperform `method4b` and `method5` a little bit.

Comment: Very good.  I got 200-227 µs on my machine for `my_method()` and 147-152 µs for `my_method2()` (N = 160).  Not as much variation as you got.  That is actually faster than the `numexpr` methods (on my machine).

Comment: I've marked this as the best answer but that's only based on speed.  For the case where `t**n` is needed (i.e. not always 3) then @Divakar's suggestion to use `numexpr` is the fastest.  However, I think this is the best general-purpose solution, especially when more complex computations are needed. Welcome other people's comments on this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill and GZ0, Shouldn't `idx = np.triu_indices(N)` and `raveled_idx = np.ravel_multi_index(idx, (N, N))` parts be part of the timings too?

Comment: @Divakar I assume this is a function primarily for `u` and `m` with fixed shapes, so I exclude those statements from the test (similar to `M = np.tri(N, dtype=bool)` in your solution).

Comment: @GZ0 In my timings section, I am including everything (they are one-liners). Everything is computed in that same one-line.

Comment: @Divakar You are right. I had excluded them from my `method_ne` tests. Moreover, the `numexpr`-based solution is still significantly faster when `N` is large enough (I've added the results above). The actual `N` values where the `numexpr` method performs better vary from machine to machine.

Comment: @GZ0 It just seems unfair that you are comparing all the methods and yours are getting the headstarts with those pre-computations. That `np.triu_indices(N)` would be the bottleneck across all sizes, so skipping it from timings didn't look right to me for a benchmarking setup.

Comment: @Divakar My whole assumption is that the `N` value is fixed while `u` and `m` are changing frequently in a loop. This is the case in many application scenarios. Also, if the `N` values change only infrequently, precomputed indices can also be cached to boost the performance. In the case that the `N` value changes frequently, there will be added overhead as you mentioned. I've added some text in my answer to admit this.

Comment: I think @Divakar is right.  If I exclude `M = 1 - np.tri(N,dtype=bool)` and `u2D = u.reshape(N, 1)` from the test then `%timeit ne.evaluate('M*(1-u/u2D)**3*m')` takes `131 µs ± 424` on my machine which is the fastest.

Comment: @Bill Yup, for a given `N`, you could pre-compute `M` that way and re-use. That `u2D = u.reshape(N, 1)` inside `evaluate` won't hurt across all datasizes. It's virtually free on runtime. So, only need to pre-compute `M`.

Comment: @Bill and @Divakar What can be included in the precomputation depends on the changing variable in the main loop of your application. Anything that is unchanged in the main loop can become precomputation. If `u` is also unchanged, then all computations on `u` can be included in precomputation (e.g. `1 - u[idx[1]] / u[idx[0]]` and `1 - u/u[:, None]` in other methods).

Answer (score 3):

We should simplify things there to leverage broadcasting at minimal places. Upon which, we would end up with something like this to directly get the final output using `u` and `m`, like so -

```
np.triu((1-u/u.reshape(N, 1))**3*m)
```

Then, we could leverage [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) that performs noticeably better when working with transcendental operations as is the case here and also is very memory efficient. So, upon porting to `numexpr` version, it would be -

```
import numexpr as ne

np.triu(ne.evaluate('(1-u/u2D)**3*m',{'u2D':u.reshape(N, 1)}))
```

Bring in the masking part within the `evaluate` method for further perf. boost -

```
M = np.tri(N,dtype=bool)
ne.evaluate('(1-M)*(1-u/u2D)**3*m',{'u2D':u.reshape(N, 1)})
```

Timings on given dataset -

```
In [25]: %timeit method1()
1000 loops, best of 3: 521 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit method2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 417 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit np.triu((1-u/u.reshape(N, 1))**3*m)
1000 loops, best of 3: 408 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.triu(ne.evaluate('(1-u/u2D)**3*m',{'u2D':u.reshape(N, 1)}))
10000 loops, best of 3: 159 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit ne.evaluate('(1-M)*(1-u/u2D)**3*m',{'u2D':u.reshape(N, 1),'M':np.tri(N,dtype=bool)})
10000 loops, best of 3: 110 µs per loop
```

Note that another way to extend `u` to a `2D` version would be with `np.newaxis/None` and this would be the idiomatic way. Hence, `u.reshape(N, 1)` could be replaced by `u[:,None]`. This shouldn't change the timings though.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about `numexpr` module.  Thanks.  Just looking into it...  Any idea why my `method1()` took 13.9 ms on your machine and 662 µs on mine? (I'm using a 2013 MacBook Pro).

Comment: @Bill Hmm not sure. I am on a laptop, that could be it? Specs being - `Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04, RAM: 16GB, CPU Model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz (# Cores=4, # Threads=8)`.

Comment: But 13.9 ms is 21x slower!  Anyway, I got 185 µs with your `numexpr` so it's a 3.5x speedup.

Comment: Still curious as to why your simplified version `np.triu((1-u/u.reshape(N, 1))**3*m)` is slower (819 µs) than my original `method1()` with explicit broadcasting...

Comment: @Bill Also, just to be sure that it's using the correct variables, can you define `method1` with `def method1(u,m,N)` and then test out timings?

Comment: Yes, still same.  `%timeit method1(u,m,N)` is 658 µs.  Can you re-test on your side?

Comment: @Bill Still the same - `method1 : 12.6 ms ± 171 µs per loop` and `method2 : 13.5 ms ± 253 µs per loop ` and `numexpr : 141 µs ± 10.9 µs per loop`.

Comment: Could it be a version thing?  My `np.__version__` is 1.16.4.  Anyway, it doesn't matter to me just a little odd.  Your laptop is actually faster than mine on the numexpr version.

Comment: @Bill Some weird stuff's going on. On Python 2.7 I am getting - `method1 : 1000 loops, best of 3: 510 µs per loop`, `method2 : 1000 loops, best of 3: 419 µs per loop` and `numexpr : 10000 loops, best of 3: 157 µs per loop`. So, that matches out with yours.

Comment: @Bill Is your question solved by this answer? If so, can you accept it?

Comment: @Dikavar You definitely speeded it up!  But I was just waiting to see if anyone has a solution to the original question which was "is there a way to speed up vectorized calculations by taking account of the fact that you are not interested in half the values in the matrix?"  If not, I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @Bill No rush on it. Sounds fair to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer may be quite simple.  Just put zeros in the cells that you don't want to calculate and the overall calculation will be faster.  I think that might explain why `method1()` was faster than `method2()`.

Here are some tests to illustrate the point.

```
In [29]: size = (160, 160)                                                      

In [30]: z = np.zeros(size)                                                     

In [31]: r = np.random.random(size) + 1                                         

In [32]: t = np.triu(r)                                                         

In [33]: w = np.ones(size)                                                      

In [34]: %timeit z**3                                                           
177 µs ± 1.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [35]: %timeit t**3                                                           
376 µs ± 2.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [36]: %timeit r**3                                                           
572 µs ± 1.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [37]: %timeit w**3                                                           
138 µs ± 548 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit np.triu(r)**3                                                  
427 µs ± 3.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit np.triu(r**3)                                                  
625 µs ± 3.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Not sure how all this works at a low level but clearly, zero or one raised to a power takes much less time to compute than any other value.

Also interesting.  With `numexpr` computation there is no difference.

```
In [42]: %timeit ne.evaluate("r**3")                                            
79.2 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit ne.evaluate("z**3")                                            
79.3 µs ± 1.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So, I think the fastest without using `numexpr` may be this way:

```
def method5(): 
    return np.triu(1 - u/u[:, None])**3*m  
assert np.array_equal(method1(), method5())
```

```
In [65]: %timeit method1()                                                      
656 µs ± 2.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [66]: %timeit method5()                                                      
587 µs ± 5.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Or, if you are really chasing every micro-second:

```
def method4b():  
    split = N//2  
    x = np.zeros((N, N))  
    u_mat = np.triu(1 - u/u.reshape(N, 1))  
    x[:split, :] = u_mat[:split,:]**3*m  
    x[split:, split:] = u_mat[split:, split:]**3*m[split:]  
    return x 
assert np.array_equal(method1(), method4b())
```

```
In [71]: %timeit method4b()                                                     
543 µs ± 3.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [72]: %timeit method4b()                                                     
533 µs ± 7.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And @Divakar's answer using `numexpr` is the fastest overall.

***UPDATE***

Thanks to @GZ0's comment, if you only need to raise to the power of 3, this is much faster:

```
def method6(): 
    a = np.triu(1 - u/u[:, None]) 
    return a*a*a*m 
assert np.isclose(method1(), method6()).all()
```

(But there is a slight loss of precision I noticed).

```
In [84]: %timeit method6()                                                      
195 µs ± 609 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In fact it is not far off the `numexpr` methods in @Divakar's answer (185/163 µs on my machine).

Comment: The `**` operation is slow because of the overhead of handling non-integer exponents. When the exponent is a small integer like 2 or 3 it is faster to simply use `*` (e.g. `t * t * t`) instead of `**`. And there is no performance difference between zero and non-zero matrices on `*`.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I just tested that. (But there is a slight loss in precision I noticed). I will add that example. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is more likely that `**` yields more precision loss than `*` because more complex computations are likely involved.

Comment: The `**` operation has been optimized by `numexpr` (see https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#usage-notes). This optimization attributes to a significant part of its performance gain.