# fill a numpy 2D array with function in one line

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to fill a 2D numpy array efficiently based on an operation

I would like to do the following in a single line

```
1DArray = ['A','B','C','D']
N = len(1DArray)
2DArray = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range (i, N):
        2DArray[i,j] = function(1DArray[i], 1DArray[j])
```

Comment: If the `function` only works with single values, that's best you can do.  It has to be called once for each `ij` pair.

Comment: Is anything known about the `function(..)`?

Comment: Why does `j` starts from `i`?

Comment: I didn't notice the `(i,N)`.  There are a set of `numpy` functions that index or select the upper or lower triangle, `np.tri...`  But if you can write `function` using some sort of `outer` calculation, it's likely to be faster than this iterating, even if it fills in the whole array

Comment: Vectorization is only possible if `function` can be vectorized. My answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099692/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-numpy-array-calculations-when-they-only-contain-value) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
2DArray = [[0 for _ in range(i)] + [function(1DArray[i], 1DArray[j]) for j in range(i,N)] for i in range (N)]
```

`[0 for _ in range(i)]` adds 0's to the positions never affected.  You could remove that to get lists with length `N-j`

Comment: technically this is a one liner, but I suspect the OP wants something that is faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)

```
import numpy as np

i=np.triu_indices(N)
2DArray[i]=[function(1DArray[x],1DArray[y]) for x,y in zip(i[0],i[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ODArray = ['A','B','C','D']
[rx,ry] = np.meshgrid(ODArray,ODArray)
TDArray = f(rx,ry)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if other responses have actually been tested, given that python identifiers can't start with a number...

As for your question, if you wish to keep the lower tridiagonal part of the matrix equal to zero, you can simply do

```
array_1d = [1, 2, 3, 4] # or np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(array_1d, array_1d)                                                                  
array_2d = np.triu(function(X, Y))
```

This will execute the function pointwise on a 2-d mesh. Otherwise, `zip`ing the array and using list comprehensions as others responses show is about as good as you can get.